# Remove cell from WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I want to remove cell of table in Apple watch. Is there any delegate method like `commitEditingStyle` which we use in iPhone app. Or any user interface like gesture or any thing so i can remove cell and data which i want at runtime. I already use `didSelectRowAtIndex` for navigate to other controller so please give me a other way.So, i can maintain both events. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you reload tableview by deleting it from model?

Comment: No, i only want any event for apply my method of remove. like didSelectRowAtIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way. Context menu could be used but it works for full controller, and there is no way to detect row/coordinates. The best way when user clicks on row you display detail controller with delete button or context menu

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 5

If you are looking to delete one of the rows, you can do this.

1. add a remove row function.
2. add the didSelectRowAt function
3. add an alert function to the didSelectRowAt
4. then add the remove function to the alert
5. also add a cancel button to the alert.

> ```
> func removeRow(at row: Int) {
> array.remove(at: row)
> self.loadTable()
> }
>
> override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int) {
>
>     let delete = WKAlertAction(title: "Delete Item", style: .default) {
>         self.removeRow(at: rowIndex)
>         self.userDefaults.setValue(self.array, forKey: "items")
>     }
>     
>     let cancel = WKAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .cancel) {}
>     
>     self.presentAlert(withTitle: "Alert", message: "Do you want to delete this item?", preferredStyle: .alert, actions: [delete,cancel])
> }
> ```